# Delete data from related tables - Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

My tables

```
 _________________     _________________   ______________     _______________
 |_Data_academic_|     |_Data_personal_|   |_Data_other_|     |_ Tbl_detail _|
 |    Id_aca     |     |    Id_pers    |   |  Id_other  |     |   Id_detail  |
 |     Name      |     |      Name     |   |    Name    |     |    Id_aca    |
 |_______________|     |_______________|   |____________|     |    Id_pers   |
                                                              |   Id_other   |
                                                              |______________|
```

In Data_academic Id_aca is primary key.

In Data_personal Id_pers is primary key.

In Data_other Id_other is primary.

In Tbl_detail Id_detail is primary key and Id_aca , Id_aca and Id_other is foreign keys.

When I delete from Tbl_detail i want to delete the data from the other tables.
I'm using this database to work in Java.

Comment: How are these tables related (*1:1*, *1:n*, *n:m* and all that)?

Comment: The table Tbl_detail is anintermediate tables. And the tables related is 1:n

Comment: Adding cascading DELETES to the foreign key constraints will handle it for you.

Comment: I did it but It doesn't works.

Comment: I have changed something in database and now works cascade. But it doesn't delete all the datas from other tables.